# Загрузка изображений в WebView с сервера

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, webview

Есть `WebView`, в который загружается HTML с сервера. В нем есть теги `<img>`, в которых прописан короткий путь до картинки, например, `<img src="/upload/images/1.jpg" />`.

При загрузке этого HTML изображения не отображаются (только рамка). Очевидно, что не получается загрузить эти изображения из-за короткой ссылки.

Как сделать так, чтобы картинки грузились в `WebView` по полной ссылке, например, `http://www.example.com/upload/images/1.jpg`?

Нашел варианты загрузки из локальных файлов, но такой вариант не подходит.

Comment: Можете скинуть пример кода и `url`, на котором ломается? Скорей всего слеш в начале лишний.  `<img src="upload/images/1.jpg" />`

Comment: а проблема воспроизводится только в webview? если открыть в браузере все работает?

Comment: В коде: `let pubHTML = receivedPubText
 viewPubHTML.loadHTMLString(pubHTML, baseURL: nil)` и в HTML:
`<img src=\"\/upload\/images\/DSC_34122222222222.JPG\">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас задан неверный baseURL на загруженной странице. Я вижу 3 варианта:

1) **(костыльный способ)** Загружаем html в виде строки, и отображаем с корректным URL.

> PS: другие ссылки могут полететь

```
    let webView: UIWebView!
    let url: NSURL!
    let baseURL: NSURL!

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, _, err) in
        if let data = data {
            let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                webView.loadHTMLString(str, baseURL: baseURL)
            }
        }
    }
```

2) С использованием [NSURLProtocol](https://habrahabr.ru/post/237367/). Вы можете перехватить начало загрузки, и подменить неверный `NSURL`. **(очень гибкий метод, рекомендую)**

3) С использованием JS: проходитесь по всем `img` тегам, и подменяете `url`. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9825358/820795) небольшой примерчик использования. Эту операцию нужно выполнять только после того как `UIWebView` будет загружен. Это и будет **минусом** этого способа, картинки начнут подгружаться с задержкой.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую!

Comment: В моем случае помогла только вот эта ваша фраза - "У вас задан неверный baseURL" :)

Одной строкой все починилось:

`let baseURL = URL(string: "http://info.olimpiada.ru/")viewPubHTML.loadHTMLString(pubHTML, baseURL: baseURL)`